# HTML5 Tag Omission: Spec Clarification With Regards To Language

Tags: html

The HTML5 specification for tag omission (http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission) starts with the following two statements (emphasis mine):

- An html element's start tag may be omitted if **the first thing inside**
  the html element is not a comment.
- An html element's end tag may be omitted if the html element is not
  **immediately followed by** a comment.

Those to statements read similarly, but not the same and I am wondering if someon can offer clarification on what they mean.

The following case seems unambiguous - you can't remove the start or close tags:

```
<html><!-- start --> ... </html><!-- end -->
```

But what about when whitespace is introduced into the mix. Can the start tag for `html` be eliminated in the following case?

```
<html>
   <!-- comment after whitespace -->
   ...
```

Can the end tag be eliminated in a similar scenario?

```
   ...
</html>
<!-- comment after whitespace -->
```

Some of the other rules make specific mention of whitespace characters which leads me to believe that they should be taken into account. Most of the rules say "...immediately followed by..." which is different than the first bullet point listed.

Comment: I tried this in Gecko and it ignores whitespace before `<head>` and after `<body>`, just leaving the comment nodes, although interestingly it places the tag as late as possible, so that the initial comments appear before the `<html>` in the DOM but the trailing comments appear after the `<body>`.

Comment: For end tag followed by means comment first and then html end tag <! ---> </html >

Comment: @Shridhar why do you think that? That would not match what it says.

Comment: To me ( may be wrong) that sentence says html end tag can be omitted if last line is not comment line.

Comment: I guess the reason being html engine will not able to interpret if element content are ended or not. I ll have some tests and let you know.

Comment: @shridhar interesting - i would have phrased the example you give as "an html element immediately _preceded_ by a comment".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important factor here is that the phrases **first thing inside** and **immediately following** are talking about *nodes* i.e. the DOM, not *tags* or other markup, so the distinction it is making is about whether the node is a child (first thing inside) or a following sibling (immediately following).

As far as spaces go:

> An html element's start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside
>   the html element is not a comment.

The first thing inside an html element cannot be a space character because at that point in the parser algorithm, space character tokens are discarded and not added to the DOM.

> An html element's end tag may be omitted if the html element is not
>   immediately followed by a comment.

Space characters, regardless of whether they appear just before or just after the `</html>` tag, end up inside the html element (in fact, also inside the body element), so the comment will be immediately following the html element regardless of whether there are spaces in between in the markup.

Comment: Isn't this statement parser dependent? "The first thing inside an html element cannot be a space character because at the point in the parser algorithm, space character tokens are discarded and not added to the DOM."

Comment: @davemankoff - No. The question is about a quote from the HTML5 (work in progress) spec. The HTML5 spec is completely specific about the parser algorithm, to the extent that any stream of bytes is parsed in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 2):

In html, space between tags doesn't matter. `<html>         <head>` and `<html><head>` are the same thing to the browser. In content (e.g. between words inside a span/p tag) it's rendered up by the browser, but when you want to use space between elements (as a design resource) you should use &nbsp.

So, as I see, **immediately followed by** doesn't mean "the next character" but "the first thing after the place that end tag was supposed to be, no matter how many spaces between them.

Then, removing html tags in both cases would invalidate the html, because no matter how many spaces are betweeen the place `</html>` was supposed to be and the comment.

edit: I think they were trying to express the same thing by using another words and avoid being repetitive, but ended up being confuse;

Answer (score 1):

The rules about tag omission are somewhat misleading in that for the most part they're not actually saying *when* tags can be omitted, but rather how they should be interpreted when they are omitted. Take, for example, the following document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!-- A comment --><title>A title</title>
```

This is a valid HTML5: you can run it through [the W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) yourself. But [the tag omission rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) clearly state that

> [a]n `html` element's start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside the `html` element is not a comment.

How do we reconcile this? The answer is that these are disambiguation rules. Because an `html` element's start tag may not be omitted if the first thing inside it is a comment, we are free to assume when parsing that the comment is *not* the first thing inside the `html` element. Similarly, the tag omission rules state that

> [a] `body` element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the `body` element is not a space character or a comment [...]

So we are free to assume that the comment is also *not* the first thing inside the `body` element. So in fact this document can be unambiguously parsed as equivalent to

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!-- A comment --><html><head><title>A title</title></head><body></body></html>
```

The parser algorithm for HTML5 specifies that if we are in the [before html](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-before-html-insertion-mode) insertion mode, which is the state the parser transitions to after seeing `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and we see

> A character token that is one of U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION, "LF" (U+000A), "FF" (U+000C), "CR" (U+000D), or U+0020 SPACE

then we are to "Ignore the token." If on the other hand we see a comment token, then we are to

> Insert a comment as the last child of the Document object.

It's not until we see some other kind of tag that we emit an `html` element. So we should expect this behavior not to be affected by whitespace, and indeed both Firefox 54 and Chrome 60 interpret the document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
         <!-- A comment -->
    <title>A title</title>
```

identically to

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!-- A comment --><title>A title</title>
```

That is, both of them are treated like

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!-- A comment --><html><head><title>A title</title></head><body></body></html>
```