# Are we allowed to omit the opening body tag if the first thing inside it is comment?

Tags: html

Very new to HTML here. HTML5 specification specifies that we are allowed to omit the opening body tag if the element does not start with an comment. However, if you run this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Page</title></head>
<!-- fsd --></body>
</html>
```

At [www.validator.w3.org/](https://validator.w3.org/), then it does not show an error despite the fact that placing a comment as first thing inside a body element when omitting an opening tag is not allowed.

Comment: It doesn't matter, because to check, you'd need to verify the behavior in every browser on every device.  "Allowed" has no meaning here. So why would you? This sounds like an "XY problem." Don't worry about the HTML validator, valid/invalid HTML doesn't tell you much about how the page will look.

Comment: Interesting, whats the purpose of omitting the opening tag anyways?

Comment: why would you want to do that at all?

Comment: @AndyRay Because the validator is error checking. To fail the validator means your markup has errors. It would be a poor programmer who would think running his code or markup with errors doesn't matter.

Comment: Googling for that line from the HTML spec reveals several previous SO questions, including this one [HTML5 Tag Omission: Spec Clarification With Regards To Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989937/html5-tag-omission-spec-clarification-with-regards-to-language)

Comment: And no, really, don't worry about the validator, unless you work for W3C. Invalid HTML doesn't affect SEO, page load time, DOM parse time, page display, maintainability, gzipping. It's only relevant to the validator. It finds accessibility errors but other tools do that. Check any of your favorite website's HTML, none will be "valid." It's not a concern for professional software development.

Comment: @AndyRay I can't think of any more false, misleading or bad advice than what you just wrote